# Rigging an Umbrella and Weight Paint

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I have been trying to weight paint an umbrella to rig bones. However, I haven't been able to resolve the edges furthest away from the bones. They overlap when the umbrella is near closing. I have looked at [this post](http://aligorith.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/rigging-umbrella-in-action.html) for rigging an umbrella including the weight paint and I have tried to replicate it but I have not been successful. Would be really happy to hear suggestions of how to properly rig an umbrella and/or assign vertex weight paint colors.

link to my rig file: [rig file link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/02zcktacoj8bjwf/rig_test02.blend?dl=0)

[image: umbrella near open, works fairly well]
[image: umbrella half open, works fairly well]
[image: umbrella when closed, and with many overlaps]

Here are screenshots of my current weight painting vertex weights as they are in the screenshots above.

[image: non working vertex weight colors]

and here are working vertex colors from the link. Although, the umbrella I am working is upside down in normal open position, I don't understand why it doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The initial mesh cannot be subdivided more than the number of bone ribs. Each vertex should be mapped to a bone. Watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2aAyp6Wjos) on rigging an umbrella in 3ds Max gave me the answer.

I had basically overcomplicated the problem by subdivisions assigned with weights in between the two ribs.

In other words, I have 6 ribs for the umbrella, with 4 bones along the umbrella mesh. Each bone gets mapped to a vertex.